# Calculating confidence Interval for a return time curve, via non-parametric bootstrapping

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, extreme-value, gumbel-distribution

I have some precipitation data (yearly extremes), which I have fit with a Gumbel distribution (CDF), from which I have calculated a return time distribution. I want to calculate the 95% confidence interval for this return time distribution, using non-parametric bootstrapping. How can I do this in python?

See below for a picture of the confidence interval I want to recreate.

[image]